# AWS SCP: Deny action "RunEC2" when you have 2 conditions

Tags: amazon-web-services

I don't undertand why my SCP is not working as I expected or how can I do this..

I want to block "Run EC2 instances" without a certain tag ONLY if the instance is not created by Data Pipeline.

I was testing diff options and I tried this:

```
{
            "Sid": "Name",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:RunInstances",
                "ec2:CreateVolume"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/cost_center": "true"
                },
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:CalledVia": [
                        "datapipeline.amazonaws.com"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
```

Why doesn't it work?
This SCP always allows EC2 creation (by datapipeline and EC2 instances console without tags)